# How to disable typed arrays in firefox as rowhammer mitigation

Tags: web-browser, firefox, memory, rowhammer

I am concerned about the potential attack surface exposed by JavaScript typed arrays as a means of performing [rowhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer) [attacks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06955).

Is it possible to disable (via official means or otherwise) typed arrays in firefox?

Answer (score 2):

There are no means to disable typed arrays in the browser. Much like you can't disable the use of 'img src' or 'a href' tags in the code.

What you can do however is prevent the execution of javascript via this method.

**In Firefox**

1. typed 'about:config' in the address bar
2. Click "I accept the risk" on the dialogue box that comes up
3. Type 'javascript.enabled' in the search section
4. Right click on 'javascript.enabled' and select 'Toggle'
5. You can then close the tab.

Firefox will not load javascript from then on.

Comment: Unfortunately, client security is not a concern for site developpers, and many site can simply not be used without javascript. IMHO it is a shame, but life is like that...

Comment: @SergeBallesta yeah man. That's why there's check and balances to minimise the risk. Guides like OWASP top 10, OWASP ASVS, Secure Coding Best Practices. With the guides, there's really no excuse not to follow.